# Annoying lock screen timeout in Windows 8 64 bits (no pro). How to configure it?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, screensaver

I don't know why or when it started. I just noticed that the laptop where I have Windows 8 has an absurdly short timeout to lock the screen. The screen that is shown is the picture of the current user prompting for password.

I have tried many things in an attempt to get rid of it. Note that this version of Windows 8 is not Pro or Enterprise and It does not have the gpedit.msc tool:

- In the screen options, in screensaver, no screen saver is set, but the timeout field steel controls when the screen will be locked or turned off, so I set value 0 there, and it changes to the string "(Never)". Also I unchecked "prompt for password". But screen steel locks.
- Googling I found that there is a policy, editable in gpedit (no available in this edition of Windows), to set the timeout to lock the screen. Then I looked for the registry key that sets that policy and changed it (but it seems that it has no effect at all, screen still locks with a timeout of 1 min approx). The key I edited is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\InactivityTimeoutSecs". I didn't existed, so I created It as DWORD with a large value.

Machine is SAMSUNG ATIV Book 2, in case somebody knows of any software that comes by default that may be causing this. I uninstalled the trial security software and I'm using Windows alone with Windows Defender and my common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to "Run".
2. Type "regedit"
3. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
4. Create a new key - name it Personalization.
5. In the Personalization key, choose New again and add a DWORD (32-bit Value) named NoLockScreen.
6. Change the value from 0 to 1.
7. Enjoy a timout-free life.

[Sourced from fixedbyvonnie](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/11/disable-delay-lock-screen-windows-8/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

> Start/Search and type gpedit.msc, Right click the gpedit results and
>   Run As Administrator. In the Elevated Group Policy Editor, on the Left
>   Panel, go to User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control
>   Panel/Personalization/Enable Screen Saver and enable the Policy.
>   Once you have enabled that policy, go down and also enable Screen
>   Saver Timeout.  Note that in the Screen Saver Timeout policy there's
>   an option to set the number of second for the timeout with the default
>   being 900 seconds or 15 minutes.
>
> Once you've enabled both policies and set the timeout if different
>   from the default, exit the group policy editor.  If you now go the
>   screen saver settings in Control Panel you will notice that the wait
>   period will match the minutes you entered in the group policy editor
>   but it will be grayed out preventing you from changing the value
>   unless you go back into the group policy editor and change it there.