# How to change Windows 10 lock screen timeout?

Tags: windows-10, security, power-management, lock-screen

**Problem:** My computer has recently begun to lock itself after ONE minute.
It's not the screensaver, it's not the stand-by mode, **it's the lock screen.**
(Win10 Enterprise, 21H2)

**Things I've tried:**

1. I have already followed [these steps to enable the power plan setting "Conrosle lock display off time-out"](https://superuser.com/a/1423624/9350) and then set that time-out to a sensible value. This alone did not help.
2. I have also checked [these screensaver settings](https://superuser.com/a/1676526/9350); the screensaver was disabled and timeout was set to 1 minute; I enabled it and set it to 33 minutes. Did not help either.
3. Many other SuperUser posts refer to the same ploblem, with many pieces of advice, but few success stories ([three](https://superuser.com/q/868126/9350), [four](https://superuser.com/a/819937/9350), [five](https://superuser.com/a/998859/9350)). I could not get these to work for me.

I even created a Regedit .REG file to repeat this easily after reboots:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; This aims to disable the screen-lock timeout so it is not set to 1 minute.

; https://superuser.com/a/868128
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"InactivityTimeoutSecs"=dword:000f423f

; https://superuser.com/a/1423624
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]
"Attributes"==dword:00000002
; Then enter the Edit Plan Settings window, find Display node, 
; Console lock display off timeout property and set it to anything. 
; Use 0 to turn the feature completely off.

; https://superuser.com/a/819937
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows]
"NoLockScreen"==dword:00000001

; https://superuser.com/a/998860
; launch gpedit.msc
; User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Personalization/Enable Screen : enable
; User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Personalization/Screen Saver Timeout : enable + value 1800
```

[image]

Comment: Does this happen when booting into Safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue with a computer at work - screen was locking after 15 seconds.
What worked for me was MANUALLY changing the registry setting above,

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]

"InactivityTimeoutSecs". It was originally set to "f", which is hex for "15".
```

I changed it to "fff", and on the next reboot, the problem behavior stopped.