Can't increase screen-lock time beyond 15 minutes on a Windows 11 system
Using a Microsoft Surface Laptop 3 running Windows 11 (upgraded from Windows 10 a few months ago). The device used to be connected to the Active Directory we use at work - after the employer allowed me to own it as my personal device, I disconnected it from the corporate AD and I have been using it since then with a private/personal Microsoft account.
Yet, I can't configure the screensaver "Wait" time to more than fifteen (15) minutes. Any value higher than 15 minutes I enter in the "Wait" counter in the Screensaver configuration box, it gets reset to 15. I cannot completely disable the screensaver either (set the "Wait" timer to zero -0- minutes).
I had this problem while I was using Windows 10 on the system and it "survived" through an upgrade to Windows 11.
I suspect that the laptop has received some relevant domain policy back when it was joined to the corporate AD that somehow has not been removed from it when I switched to WORKGROUP. I have been trying to fix this for months researching a lot on the Internet and applying different solutions - have not had any success so far, though.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Panos.

Which screen-locker/saver do you use, and where are you setting the timeout? What do you have in Settings > System > Power & battery > Screen and sleep > When plugged in, turn off my screen after?

Two things to try: 1. Change the value in the Registry - https://superuser.com/questions/1746722/how-to-change-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout . 2. Give a longer grace period before the PC actually locks -- the screensaver will show during that period,  but any input (e.g., mouse move, key click) will return to the desktop. See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/47389-change-screen-saver-password-grace-period-windows.html

@harrymc, thank you for your comment. This happens for all screensavers. All settings in "Screen and sleep" sectio are configured to "Never".

@drMoishePippik, thanks for these hints. Adding the registry key didn't help (actually, there was no "System" key in that section of the registry). I don't think the 2nd post is relevant to my problem - I have tried with different grace periods - always failed to configure a screen-lock time higher than fifteen (15) minutes.

Just to clarify: the problem is that I can't configure the screensaver "Wait" time to any value higher than fifteen (15) minutes. The dialog box appears to accept a higher value (for example: thirty -30- minutes - when I go back into it, though, the "Wait" value is set to fifteen (15) minutes. I have amended the original question to make that clear.

If you click on the "Never" for "turn off my screen after", can you choose longer times than 15 minutes?

@harrymc, I can set higher times like 1 or 3 hours / etc. - however, these are related to screen-sleep / device-sleep times. No matter what I set in there, my screensaver still starts in fifteen (15) minutes and I am not allowed to configure a longer time.

I believe I have found the root of this problem: "Local Security Policy" snap-in shows that policy "Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit" in section "Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options" in "Local Security Policy" snap-in was set to 900 seconds (or 15 minutes). Once I I changed that value to 86400 seconds (1440 minutes = 1 day), I am now allowed to enter a higher value in the "Wait" counter in the screensaver configuration options - up to 1440 minutes. All I need to confirm now is that the local policy does not reset to 900 seconds after a system restart.

Just came back from a system restart. Both the "Machine inactivity limit" option in "Local Security Policy" snap-in and the screensaver timer have kept the values I configured (86400 & 1440 respectively). It seems the issue has been fixed. I have been inspecting all "Local Security Policy" settings for months - i wonder how on earth I have miseed that seeting! I am now going to keep the system idle for at least twenty (20) minutes to make sure nothing else forces the screensaver to kick in.

I was able to fix this after I found out that policy "Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit" in section "Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options" in "Local Security Policy" snap-in was set to 900 seconds (or 15 minutes). Once I changed that value to 86400 seconds (1440 minutes = 1 day), I was able to enter a higher value in the "Wait" counter in the screensaver configuration options - up to 1440 minutes. The change persists through system restarts - therefore, I believe this is a permanent fix.
